# Using Migrate in Drupal 6, setup and parsing XML

Tags: views, 6, migrations

Is there a better walkthrough to setting up Migrate than [this](http://drupal.org/migrate) documentation on Drupal.org? I have followed those directions, and I can't get my classes to show up in the UI. Is there anything clearer?

And how would I go about using Migrate, once it's set up, to parse a series of XML documents (one list XML that includes an additional document per node) into nodes which I can then manipulate in Views?

**EDIT**
Now I've gotten my XML read and fields set up (I think), but now I can't get the nodes to save. The import has the correct number of nodes, but they don't ever get imported. The wine examples in the documentation didn't say anything about using prepareRow() or anything when you are using XML. Where are my nodes? Can I pull out that data with Views even if nodes don't import? My end use for this is to arrange everything with Views.

Comment: Frankly I didn't find any documentation better than that. You have to follow carefully the instructions about files naming and classes naming. About your migration task: it can be done.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a problem with the way I named my files. I tried to follow that tutorial exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, look at the [Beer examples](http://drupalcode.org/project/migrate.git/tree/2252a4daa609ebc77287162bb6ae1f1772cec16e:/migrate_example) that come in the migrate module itself. If you want some example code and usage with some explanation I find the [BTMash blog posts useful](http://btmash.com/tags/migrate). While the BTMash blog is D7 based -- the hooks and usage of Migrate is widely similiar between D6 and D7.